# Runnable: Как изменить счетчик?

Tags: java

Как я понимаю, что можно было обратиться к переменной из Runnable, она должна быть final, но тогда ее нельзя менять. Как это обойти?

```
final int n = 0;

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        n++;
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

почему бы не заимплементировать Runneble??
что то вроде:

```
public class MyRunnable implement Runnable {
private int n;
...
get\set
...
@override
public void run(){...}

}
```

Comment: И чем это отличается от варианта @Gorets?

Comment: как вы из варианта @Gorets достанете переменную??

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    int n = 0;
    public void run() {
        n++;
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: @Gorets, вряд ли @javax хочет менять переменную того же класса. IMHO ему нужен доступ к некоторой "внешней", разделяемой несколькими потоками переменной.

@javax, вне контекста задачи можно долго перебирать разные варрианты.